# How to filter an observable against object properties

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

I have an observable, `fields$: Observable<Field[]>`. I need to look at the `required` and `result` properties of each field to determine if all required fields have been populated.

I have another observable, `missingRequiredResults$: Observable<boolean>`, that I'm using to enable/disable a button via `<button type="button" [disabled]="(missingRequiredResults$ | async)">`

Here is the method I'm using to set `missingRequiredResults$`:

```js
private validateRequiredResults() {
  this.missingRequiredResults$ = this.fields$.pipe(
    map(fields => 
      fields.filter(field => {
          field.required == true && (field.result == null || field.result == '')
        }).length != 0
    )
  );
}
```

No matter what I do, `missingRequiredResults$` holds a value of `false`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it turns out it's the curly braces inside the filter method that's breaking it. I removed those and it works great.

Comment: youu need a return statement in your curly brackets

Comment: Yes you should return like this: const a = fields.filter(field.... ; return a;

Comment: @Train, if you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is missing the return statement in the curly brackets

```
private validateRequiredResults() {
  this.missingRequiredResults$ = this.fields$.pipe(
    map(fields => 
      fields.filter(field => {
          return field.required == true && (field.result == null || field.result == '') //add the return statement here
        }).length != 0
    )
  );
}
```

As you pointed out, you removed the curly brackets and it worked.